# Javascript textarea allow only a-zA-Z

Tags: javascript, validation, textarea

I have this code;

```
$('[data-question=502] textarea').bind('input propertychange', function() {
     $(this).val($(this).text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z\.]/g, ''));//  
});
```

Would somebody kindly tell me why it's not allowing me to write into my text box?

Thanks,
Harry

edit:

The regex was wrong as I was trying to get the validation to work before changing the regex.

Comment: FYI You don't need to escape the `.` in the `[class]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're replacing with the text (roughly the initial content of the textarea element), not the value.

Change

```
$(this).val($(this).text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z\.]/g, ''));//
```

to

```
$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z\.]/g, ''));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I attempt to edit the regex in your post but it wouldn't let me..

Comment: That would be why. Is the first method (the one still visible, as you removed the second) now a valid way of doing it then?

Comment: @HarryTorry I think so. In fact the most correct way would be to keep the cursor position when you remove chars but it's quite more complex (a few more lines).

Comment: Okay thanks for the help, I'll use the version that is currently in your post!